# JSON source mapping breaks the parser in Webstorm debug process

Tags: javascript, webstorm, source-maps

My problem is exactly like this one:

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/4639

While debugging my js app in WebStorm, every JSON from XMLHttpRequest response is annotated with:

```
//# sourceURL=http://localhost:63342/JSON_URL_here
```

This doesn't happen while debugging in Chrome with Jetbrains plugin deactivated, so I guess it's a fair bet that WebStorm is performing the annotation.

The problem is, the JSON file can't be parsed, throwing the following error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token /
```

Is it possible to solve this issue, other than changing the THREE source code and manually removing the problematic line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sourceURL appended to any JS file loaded via XHR (jquery load script for example). Otherwise it is impossible to set breakpoint.

You should not use ".js" file extension for JSON files, please use ".json" instead. Is it possible in your case?

Comment: Oh. Yes, I think I can switch to .json. Thanks a ton!